# tools to detect .net application deadlock

Tags: .net, deadlock

can anybody recommend tools to detect .net application deadlock?

EDIT:
[Chess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/cc950526.aspx) is what i found from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nicest tool I've seen is the Concurrency Visualizer in VS 2010.  I would recommend installing VS 2010 Ultimate Beta 2, then profiling your application with the Concurrency Profiler.

This shows you exactly where you have contention, and what is holding each lock.

Comment: cool, i will give it a shoot. is there any lightweight tool?

Comment: That's what I've been using.  Many profilers have some capabilities, but the VS one is by far more usable... (although it's very slow, atm)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to VS, you can also go more lowlevel by using [WinDBG](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/downloads.mspx) and the [sosex](http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXANewDebuggingExtensionForManagedCode.aspx) Extension; more specifically the "!dlk" command.

Granted, the learning curve with WinDBG could be a bit steep, but it could be certainly worth it - for all sorts of issues.